# NodeJs: Setting up cron server every 2 minutes but stop it in between 12am to 6 am?

Tags: node.js, cron

I need some help in setting up a cron server in which the process will run every two minutes, but stop at 12am and restart running every two minutes at 6 am.

I have already set up it to run every two minutes. Any help please ?

```
 new cronJob({
    cronTime: '0 */2 * * * *',  
    onTick: function() {
        //process run after every two minutes
    },
    start: true
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the current hour inside the `onTick`:

```
onTick : function() {
  // Don't do anything if between the hours of 12AM and 6AM.
  if (new Date().getHours() < 6) return;

  // The job code follows:
},
```

Comment: I prefer this answer to my own. Much simpler and centralised

Answer (score 1):

How about 2 other cronJobs that sets a flag on/off at 12 & 6?

```
var enabled = true;

new cronJob({
    cronTime: '0 */2 * * * *',  
    onTick: function() {
        if (enabled) {
          //process run after every two minutes
        }
    },
    start: true
});

new cronJob({
    cronTime: '0 0 12 * * *',  
    onTick: function() {
       enabled = false;
    },
    start: true
});

new cronJob({
    cronTime: '0 0 6 * * *',  
    onTick: function() {
        enabled = true;
    },
    start: true
});
```